# How to create a temporary text file in C

Tags: c

I have a text file to read. I would like to read from that file and store into a temporary file. I am not sure how to do this. How do I create a temporary file and do I use fprintf to store in that file?

Comment: Usually its nice to provide some code that you have so far to give people more context. But kindly A4L has provided you an excellent hint.

Comment: +1 just because of the stupid down-votes...  There's no reason to down-vote a new user over here since he doesn't lose reputation and <fill the other reasons in>.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the function [tmpfile()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile) for that.

> The tmpfile() function opens a unique temporary file in binary read/write (w+b) mode. The file will be automatically deleted when it is closed or the program terminates.

Example:

```
FILE * temp = tmpfile();
if(temp) {
    fprintf(temp, "Hello, Temp!");
}
```

Comment: thank you, apologies for the tardiness, this is my first post

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on Windows then you'll need to use the `GetTempPath` and `GetTempFileName` functions.

Relevant for Windows: [Create temporary file in C, MS Windows system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717271/create-temporary-file-in-c-ms-windows-system?rq=1)